# How do I put a router link inside the Quasar Input validation text?

Tags: vue.js, quasar-framework

I am using the [internal Quasar validation](https://quasar.dev/vue-components/input#validation) (`:rules`) to validate an input form.

It's an array of rules, with a boolean function on one side of the `||` and the error validation text on the other. Here is an example from the docs I linked above:

```
<q-input
    ref="inputRef"
    filled
    v-model="model"
    label="Email"
    :rules="[val => !!val || 'Email is required']"
/>
```

Now I want to include a router link within the validation text, and I can't figure out how to make that work.

For example:

```
<q-input
    ref="inputRef"
    filled
    v-model="model"
    label="Email"
    :rules="[!(await isEmailSignedUp(val)) ||
    'This email already exists. Please <router-link to='{ name: 'login' }'>login</router-link> or use a different email.',]"
/>
```

How would I make the above work?

At the moment it just prints that template code as a string.

Comment: `q-input` does not support links (or any markup) within the error message, so you would have to roll your own component that displays the error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vue is not string based templating engine. Of course this does not work. In cases like that (need to render component as part (or to replace part) of another component, always look for existing slots

In this case `q-input` has an `error` slot - [docs](https://quasar.dev/vue-components/input#example--slot-for-error-message). Unfortunately it is not a scoped slot (so it does not provide current error messages for example) so if you have more rules (and possible error messages to display) you will need more involved logic inside (possibly using `v-if` and template ref)

Note taht in order to use this slot, `bottom-slots` prop must be present on the `q-input`

```html
<q-input
    ref="inputRef"
    filled
    v-model="model"
    label="Email"
    :rules="[!(await isEmailSignedUp(val)) || 'login']"
    bottom-slots  // <-- IMPORTANT!
>
  <template v-slot:error>
    <div>This email already exists. Please <router-link to='{ name: 'login' }'>login</router-link> or use a different email.</div>
  </template>
</q-input>
```